# Connecting Pentaho BI Server to Kylin

Tags: mondrian, pentaho-report-designer, kylin

Kylin 2.1.0 is up and running on a Hadoop 2.7.0 cluster with HBase
1.2.6 and Hive 2.1.1 installed.

We also have Pentaho BI server 6.1.0.1.196 (mondrian 3.11 and saiku)
installed on another machine.

We want Pentaho to access cubes created in Kylin and use Saiku Analytics

Did refer few suggestions on internet but was unable to achieve my goal
https://github.com/mustangore/kylin-mondrian-interaction

Any help on this is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called KyAnalyzer，which integrates Mondrain and Saiku with Kylin seemlessly. 
Here is the document for this product: https://kyligence.gitbooks.io/kap-manual/en/kyanalyzer/kyanalyzer.en.html

Comment: Thankyou for the information. Need to read the product KyAnalyzer's documentation.